# Probability of winning a k+1 out of 2k+1 series.

Tags: probability

Here's the problem:

Consider a $k+1$ out of $2k+1$ series (i.e. the team which wins $k+1$ games first, wins the series). For example if $k=3$, it’s a best $4$ out of $7$ series. Assume that the games are independent and team $A$ has a probability $p$ of winning each game. Let

$$p^*(k)=P(\text{team A wins in a k+1 out of 2k+1 series})$$

Show that:
$$(i) \text{ For } p<\frac12, p^*(k) \text{ decreases as } k \text{ increases}.$$

$$(ii) \text{ For } p>\frac12, p^*(k) \text{ increases as } k \text { increases}.$$

So, I'm pretty lost on this one. We're basically given the steps to work it out, and I'm still not following it. Here's what we're given:

Let $q=1-p$ and $r=pq$. Now, let $X_k$ denote the duration of the series. Then

$$\mu _k = E[X_k]=(k+1)+(k+1)r\left[1+\sum_{i=2}^k \frac1{i+1}\binom{2i}{i}r^{i-1}\right] \text{ and}$$

$$\mu _{k+1} = \frac{k+2}{k+1}\mu _k + \binom{2k+2}{k+1}r^{k+1}$$

There's even more given, but I don't even understand where these formulas came from, so I feel like I should start with that. If anyone could expound upon this a bit for me, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is off course, but I was able to come up with a formula for the probability of winning a best of $2k+1$ series for any $p$ and $k+1 \geq 2$:

Let $k + 1 \leq n \leq 2k + 1$. We see that there are ${n-1\choose n-1-k}$ ways of winning the series in n games by combinations of where to place the $(n - 1 - k)$ losses in $(n - 1)$ positions.

Also, the probability of winning in one of those ways is $(p)^{k+1}(q)^{n-(k+1)}$.

Thus, the probability of winning the series in n games is: $$(p)^{k+1}(q)^{n-(k+1)}{n-1\choose n-1-k}$$
So the probability of winning the series becomes the sum of the probabilities of winning in k+1 games up to 2k+1 games: $$\sum\limits_{n = k + 1}^{2k+1} (p)^{k+1}(q)^{n-(k+1)}{n-1\choose n-1-k}$$

Some analysis on this will show (i) and (ii), but it doesn't make use of what you were given, so sorry if it's useless!

Comment: So, if $n=k+1$, then that binomial coefficient will always be $\binom{k}{0}$ which will always be $1$. Also, the exponent associated with $q$ will always be $(k+1)-(k+1)=0$ making that term a $1$, as well... or am I missing something?

Comment: oh n is initially k+1, then increases by 1 for each next term in the series, while k+1 is fixed. So for the first term it is k choose 0, then for the next it's (k + 1) choose 1. Sorry, I'll make the edit because that was misguiding

Comment: Ah, yes. Right. n is just the index for the sum.